# E: Unable to locate package postgresql-12

Tags: linux-mint, postgresql

I'm using Linux Mint and I'm trying to upgrade PostgreSQL 10 to version 12 through `sudo apt-get install postgresql-12`, but I see this frequent error:

```
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-12
```

So what's wrong? Can you show me why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL 12 is only available in Linux Mint 20.*x* (based on Ubuntu 20.04). Linux Mint 21.*x* (based on Ubuntu 22.04) has PostgreSQL 14, you need to use

```
sudo apt install postgresql-14
```

there. Linux Mint 19.*x* only has PostgreSQL 10.

In any release, you can use

```
sudo apt install postgresql
```

to get the default version for that release.